# What is the equivalent jade file in html?

Tags: angularjs, pug

I have to migrate a application from jade to html 5 (bootstrap 3). I read the documentation [jade template engine](http://jade-lang.com/reference/). It's useful but I did not find all the information I need. Here is the complete index.jade file:

```
html(lang='en', data-ng-app='angular-client-side-auth')
head
meta(charset='utf-8')
title Angular Auth Example
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/app.css')
link(href="/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
link(href="/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
// This is needed because Facebook login redirects add #_=_ at the end of the URL
script(type="text/javascript").
if (window.location.href.indexOf('#_=_') > 0) {
window.location = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/, '');
}
body(data-ng-cloak)
.navbar(data-ng-controller="NavCtrl")
.navbar-inner
.container-fluid
ul.nav.nav-tabs
li(data-access-level='accessLevels.anon', active-nav)
a(href='/login') Log in
li(data-access-level='accessLevels.anon', active-nav)
a(href='/register') Register
li(data-access-level='accessLevels.user', active-nav)
a(href='/') Home
li(data-access-level='accessLevels.user', active-nav='nestedTop')
a(href='/private') Private
li(data-access-level='accessLevels.admin', active-nav)
a(href='/admin') Admin
li(data-access-level='accessLevels.user')
a(href="", data-ng-click="logout()")
| Log out
div#userInfo.pull-right(data-access-level='accessLevels.user')
| Welcome&nbsp;
strong {{ user.username }}&nbsp;
span.label(data-ng-class='{"label-info": user.role.title == userRoles.user.title, "label-success": user.role.title == userRoles.admin.title}') {{ user.role.title }}
.container(data-ui-view)
#alertBox.alert.alert-danger(data-ng-show="error")
button(type="button", class="close", data-ng-click="error = null;") &times;
strong Oh no!&nbsp;
span(data-ng-bind="error")
script(src='/components/angular/angular.min.js')
script(src='/components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js')
script(src='/components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js')
script(src='/js/routingConfig.js')
script(src='/js/app.js')
script(src='/js/services.js')
script(src='/js/controllers.js')
script(src='/js/filters.js')
script(src='/js/directives.js')
// Partial views... Load up front to make transitions smoother
script(type="text/ng-template", id="404")
include partials/404
script(type="text/ng-template", id="admin")
include partials/admin
script(type="text/ng-template", id="home")
include partials/home
script(type="text/ng-template", id="login")
include partials/login
script(type="text/ng-template", id="private/layout")
include partials/private/layout
script(type="text/ng-template", id="private/home")
include partials/private/home
script(type="text/ng-template", id="private/nested")
include partials/private/nested
script(type="text/ng-template", id="private/nestedAdmin")
include partials/private/nestedAdmin
script(type="text/ng-template", id="register")
include partials/register
```

What is the equivalent html/js of the two following tags:

1. **li(data-access-level='accessLevels.anon', active-nav)
   a(href='/login') Log in**
2. **script(type="text/ng-template", id="404")
   include partials/404**

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why not just compiling it?

Comment: Thanks Ilan Frumer. It's my first time to work with jade. So i've compiled it and i get the equivalent html.

Answer (score 1):

1 = IF the user is not authenticated (accessLevels.anon) then activate (show) the Login link on the nav bar

2) Show the 404 error page located in the partials folder

Answer (score 1):

You can check here - http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/

1

```
<li data-access-level="accessLevels.anon" active-nav> </li><a href="/login">Log in</a>
```

2

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="404">  ... 'included partial html' ... </script>
```